# Is there any way to automatically unblock the MS Teams bot when we install it again?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

The MS Teams bot gets blocked when we uninstall the bot. The bot does not unblock itself when we install it again. We have to manually unblock it, or else messages do not get sent to the bot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7S7r.png)

I uninstalled the bot, and the Chat tab of the bot is now blocked. We want to know if there is any way to automatically unblock the bot when we re-install it?

Comment: Someone from Teams may comment on here, but as far as I know, no, you cannot automatically unblock the bot.

Comment: There is no way to automatically unblock the MS Teams Bot.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, if MS teams automatically blocks the bot/app when user uninstall it then it should unblock the bot automatically when we re-install it. right?

Comment: @DeveshTiwari - In the scenario when you uninstall the bot, the bot blocks itself so that no conversation can happen. But when you reinstall that bot, it automatically unblocks itself. We have tested this scenario as well.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, I am not sure if we are doing something different but here is the video showing how Teams is behaving when we uninstall/re-install our app. Bot does not unblock itself. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1spR62pBXr3tERoCH7LZ4eaQGTEVXVud2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I observed from the video, your app was initially added to personal scope and after uninstalling you have added in teams scope, and you checked the blocking/unblocking status for app added in personal scope. Could you please try adding the app in personal scope and check if it works?

Comment: In our current flow, user install the bot in teams scope and receives the proactive welcome message in bot chat window. We had installed the bot in a Team and not in personal scope. We uninstalled it and reinstalled the bot to the Team again. Is this the expected behavior or the bot will automatically unblock itself when added to the team again?

Comment: The bot should automatically unblock itself when added to team again.